# Quelle formulation est la meilleure: « C’est la perspective de quelque chose après la mort » ou «C’est pour la perpective de... »?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, formulation

Contexte.

Pourquoi les gens croient aux fantômes? C’est pour rigoler? Non. 1- C’est la perspective de quelque chose après la mort. 2- C’est la perspective d’un quelque chose après la mort. 3- C’est pour la perspective de quelque chose après la mort. 4- C’est pour la perspective d’un quelque chose après la mort.

La tournure 1- renvoie à des propos tenus dans un film et je trouvais qu’elle sonnait mal...(même si grammaticalement la phrase semble se tenir) sans doute due à une précision ou un à détail manquant.

Si « pour » ne convient pas, ne faudrait-il pas que « parce que » introduise la phrase? Il est à noter que dans le contexte il y a un adverbe interrogatif, et généralement, de mémoire, il appelle une locution conjonctive (parce que) ou une préposition (pour) exprimant la cause, non?

Merci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cette déduction est la mienne. Ceci est un cas courant de continuation par le présentatif "c'est" qui ne fait que formuler la description d'un agent dans le contexte expliquant la raison, sans stipuler ce qu'est le rôle de cet agent dans le contexte. Les causes de ce type de réaction ne sont pas toujours claires : elles peuvent être la perception du contexte par le locuteur, perception dans laquelle l'agent se détache par dessus tout alors qu'il/elle n'est pas apte à saisir parfaitement le rôle ou incapable de lui trouver un terme qui convienne ; une autre possibilité peut être que le rôle est plus ou moins évident.

- C’est la perspective de quelque chose après la mort **qui induit les gens à y croire**.
  (*Ils croient parce qu'ils sont induits à croire et donc on a explicitement le pourquoi.*)

Dans ce qui n'est qu'une possibilité dans la continuation complète ci-dessus, on devrait, selon des critères d'expression plus rationnels dire plutôt ceci.

- C'est parce que les gens sont induits à y croire par/du fait de la perspective de quelque chose après la mort.

Je trouve donc exacte votre perception de ce problème d'expression.

« 1 » et « 2 » sont les meilleurs choix (dans l'optique du type d'expression « à peu près »).